# How can I create audio visualizer for Qt WebEngineView?

Tags: qt, audio, visualizer, qwebengineview

There are some Qt audio visualizer example. But these are written for multimedia classes. How can I get audio of web view video (youtube, dailymotion etc..). And how can I 2d graphically visualize it at the same time? (If possible in qml)